# Delphi: en/decode for some function

Tags: delphi, decode

this is a decode function for hexadecimal value,
I tried to figure out the encode function for it, but no luck.

```
function dtwin(flg: Integer): Integer;
var i:integer;
ner,yrd, yrv :Cardinal;
unr :Int64;
begin
     ner := 1;
     unr := flg;
     yrd := $2E8CFFB0;
     yrv := $0C8CFFF0;
  for i := 1 to 32 do
   begin
    if (yrv and 1) <> 0 then
      begin
       ner := ((ner * unr) mod (yrd));
      end;
     unr := ((unr * unr) mod (yrd));
    yrv := (yrv shr 1) and $7FFFFFFF;
   end;
    Result := ner;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe decoding is supposed to be hard.

Comment: At least you could format the code you asking us to examine.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is:  It can't be done.

Please read:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Let b = flg

Let e = $0C8CFFF0 = 210567152

Let m = $2E8CFFB0 = 780992432

Then this function is calculating  ( b ^ e ) mod m

To reverse it, we need to find the multiplicative inverse of e mod m.

I tried using WolframAlpha.

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=multiplicative+inverse+of+210567152+mod+780992432](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=multiplicative%20inverse%20of%20210567152%20mod%20780992432)

The result it gives is:

> (210567152 is not invertible modulo 780992432)

The reason is that e and m are not co-prime. They are both divisible by two.

From this we can conclude that there is no way to reverse this function because there are colissions.
As an example:

> dtwin(60) = dtwin(2326) = 62188800

What should the reverse function return when called with the parameter 62188800?
Should it return 60 or 2326?

Here are some more examples of collisions:

```
dtwin(658) = dtwin(1300) = 682595280
dtwin(60) = dtwin(2326) = 62188800
dtwin(1316) = dtwin(2600) = 76519712
dtwin(2312) = dtwin(3522) = 317601904
dtwin(1974) = dtwin(3900) = 52357088
dtwin(120) = dtwin(4652) = 144155936
dtwin(2632) = dtwin(5200) = 679101872
dtwin(3290) = dtwin(6500) = 322955216
dtwin(3989) = dtwin(6725) = 301338273
dtwin(180) = dtwin(6978) = 628048624
dtwin(4624) = dtwin(7044) = 435300992
dtwin(5080) = dtwin(7658) = 2152880
dtwin(3948) = dtwin(7800) = 682904608
dtwin(2685) = dtwin(8183) = 461799889
dtwin(2461) = dtwin(8951) = 170465
dtwin(4606) = dtwin(9100) = 138445536
dtwin(240) = dtwin(9304) = 231258592
dtwin(4741) = dtwin(9603) = 586985553
dtwin(6117) = dtwin(9923) = 277591073
```

To generate results that could be useful for encryption, you can generate numbers as follows.
I won't go into details here about how this works. You can Google public key cryptography if you need to know more.

```
Select P and Q that are prime.
Compute N = P * Q
Compute T = (P-1) * (Q-1)   This is called the totient.
Select E that is coprime to N and T.
Select D that is the multiplicative inverse of E mod T.
```

Your modulus is N.  The two exponents are E and D.

```
To encrypt A, calculate B = ( A ^ E ) mod N
To decrypt B, calculate A = ( B ^ D ) mod N
```

Note that in real-world encryption, these values typically have hundreds or thousands of digits.

Here are some results that are in the order of magnitude of your examples:

```
N = 590108483 =$232C5743
E = 547145911 =$209CC8B7
D = 507147559 =$1E3A7527

N = 763464677 =$2D818BE5
E = 545809367 =$208863D7
D = 622691303 =$251D83E7

N = 948703211 =$388C0FEB
E = 885205759 =$34C32AFF
D = 893844127 =$3546FA9F

N = 897918037 =$35852455
E = 894567871 =$355205BF
D = 539129719 =$20227777

N = 754905647 =$2CFEF22F
E = 540902531 =$203D8483
D = 534729131 =$1FDF51AB
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I got yrd and yrv mixed up in my instructions to you.   yrd is the modulus and must be the same in the two routines.  The yrv's must be multiplicative inverse.   May I ask, what do yrd and yrv stand for?

Comment: I have to apologize.  The method I gave for generating valid modulus and exponents was wrong.  I've modified the answer to give the correct method, and provide some working examples.